# Multi-display issues T61 on 12.04 TLS

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, display

Installed 12.04 LTS on T61 laptop. I have issues on Multi-displays. Problems come when trying to make changes to Multi displays and save . Both screens blacken , when click the mouse noise on both screens appear

Comment: We need to know what kind of video card the laptop has, please add that to your question!

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth: I observed similar screen 'noise' immediately after installing 12.04 on my dual monitor desktop.

This issue went away after completing installation of the 270 or so software updates that were pending since the 12.04 installation iso file was created. Also, I had to use 'unity 2D' to get good display behavior, but I think this is due to my graphics hardware limitations.